# How do Miner Trees work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

How exactly does a Miner Tree (Twilight Forest) work? Does it literally PULL ore from below it to the surface, thereby removing the ore that was below it, or does it COPY ore that is below it and place the copies around it at the surface? What if I place ores below it manually? How large of an area does it effect? What are all the quirks and tricks and behaviors of this wonderfull tree?

Comment: What mod is it from? My search-fu fails me!

Comment: no way it's going to dupe ores, that one thing no FTB mod does

Comment: @SevenSidedDie twilight forest

Comment: Yes it duz pull it to the surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Miner's Tree is a type of "magic" tree that is added by the Twilight Forest mod. It cannot be found naturally at any currently known location within the forest and must be grown from a Miner's Tree Sapling. It is made up of Minewood, Miner's Leaves and a single Minewood Core at a height of three blocks in the "hilt" of the "pickaxe" formation that the Miner's Tree takes on. The Minewood Core gives this tree the special property that it will pull ores up to the surface, similar to the function of the Ore Magnet.

**Here's The Properties of an Ore Magnet:**

> The Ore Magnet is an item that is sometimes found as loot in chests in large Hollow Hills. The Ore Magnet, true to its name, is an item which brings ores closer to the player. This functions with most ores, even mod ores such as Xychorium Ore, Copper, Tin, Silver, and so forth, as long as the block has Ore in its name; essentially, any block other than Dirt, Stone, Obsidian, and other naturally-occurring and common underground blocks will be pulled closer to the player.

Short answer, from what I found out, it seems like the Miner Trees *pulls* the ores towards it.

Sources:

- [Miner Tree – FTB Wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Miner%27s_Tree)
- [Ore Magnet - FTB Wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Ore_Magnet)

Comment: Please use quote formatting when cutting and pasting from other sites to make it clear what words are being copied and which are your own.